# How to put line name and then line in section using bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

How do i put line then name and line in using bootstrap in mvc project

Comment: Any code snippets?

Comment: I am new to bootstarp, how  can i do ?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? A navbar? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/ Your question is very unclear.

Comment: The name " browse by  category " followed by line, i want line name and then line.

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to Bootstrap actually as you can achieve this using just regular CSS whether you're working on a Bootstrap project or not.

Here is my flexbox approach:

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="decorated">
        Browse By Category
    </h1>
</div>
```

```css
.decorated {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.decorated:before, 
.decorated:after{
    content: "";
    flex: 0 1 10%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.decorated:before {
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.decorated:after {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

The key here is `flex: 0 1 10%;` property on `:before` and `:after`:

- 0: means you disable the growing on remaining empty space. If you want the lines take up the entire line, set it to 1
- 1: means you enable the shrinking on not-enough space.
- 10%: the size before remaining space is distributed. You can set it to a fixed width like `4rem` as well.

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/0sme3xq9/43/

If you want to utilize Bootstrap Flexbox classes, you can take out `.decorated` styles and put flexbox classes on the element instead:

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="decorated d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
        Browse By Category
    </h1>
</div>
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/0sme3xq9/46/